# Why html media query works wrong?

Tags: html, css

Actually I am new in html and css.

I have one issue connected with css media queries. I simply want to change my body background color.
Here my code:

```css
@media (max-width: 1000px){
  body{
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

Finally I got following issue.
background color keeps red only since screen  < 666px the place it would be < 1000px.

in 666px screen width, my body color still red but i wondering why the body width approximately 980px.
screenshot in case of 666px
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5uikwd3ifkodqlr/Capture.JPG?dl=0

And in 667px screen width, my body become white.

screenshot in case of 667px 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ybbu94bnxgcxezy/Capture2.JPG?dl=0

can anyone tell me where is my mistake ?

Comment: create a fildle which shows the issue.

Comment: may be you're overriding the media query, with simple code like you've won't cause that...

Comment: @Fuzzyma Or, better, use [stack snippets](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)

Comment: Have you zoomed in the browser window?

Comment: the code is written totally pure, there is nothing to be overwritten, 
you are now seeing all the code, which I have

Comment: thank you Juhana, all the problem was with Zooming the window

Comment: Since media query also depends on the screen resolution. In the image it is show 984.00 for 666px screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use media queries at the end of your style sheet.

media queries look like that:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px){
 body{
  background-color: red;
 }
}
```

also take care that you overwrite the css correctly for example u set a background to #container.col-8.content then you should use the same in your queries

also you have to put this in the `<head>` of your document:

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0;' />
```